# ExcelApplication..Workbooks.OpenText has genereted an exception

Tags: excel, delphi, automation

I have an error on the line " ExcelApplication.Workbooks.OpenText". It's very strange because the error appear just on one server (against thousands PC installed).
The error message is "The server has generated an exception". I haven't error code or more explanation.

The second strange point is, if I start Excel just before, the "OpenText" works fine.

My test code is :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lcid: integer;
  ExcelApplication: TExcelApplication;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  lcid := GetUserDefaultLCID;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('TExcelApplication.Create(nil)');
  ExcelApplication := TExcelApplication.Create(nil);

  try
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Connect');
      ExcelApplication.Connect;
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Excption 1');
        showmessage('connect ' + e.Message +' ' + e.StackTrace)
      end;
    end;
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Workbooks.OpenText');
      ExcelApplication.Workbooks.OpenText(Edit1.Text,
        { Origin:= } xlWindows,
        { StartRow:= } 1,
        { DataType:= } xlDelimited,
        { TextQualifier:= } xlDoubleQuote,
        { ConsecutiveDelimiter:= } False,
        { Tab:= } True,
        { Semicolon:= } True,
        { Comma:= } False,
        { Space:= } False,
        { Other:= } False,
        { FieldInfo:= } EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
        EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, lcid);

    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Excption 2');
        showmessage(e.Message);
      end;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Visible[lcid] := True;');
    ExcelApplication.Visible[lcid] := True;
    // JP le 07/01/2016
    // Pas sur que ca passe sur tous les Excels. A voir....
    // On selectionne tout
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Cells.Select;');
    ExcelApplication.Cells.Select;
    // On ajoute le filtre auto sur les entêtes de colonnes
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Cells.AutoFilter(1, EmptyParam, xlAnd, EmptyParam, True);;');
    ExcelApplication.Cells.AutoFilter(1, EmptyParam, xlAnd, EmptyParam, True);;
    // On retaille toutes les colonnes
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit');
    ExcelApplication.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit;
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Disconnect;');
    ExcelApplication.Disconnect;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ExcelApplication.Free;');
    ExcelApplication.Free;
  end;

end;
```

The server have Excel 2016.
I use the uses "Excel2010".

Comment: If I had this lines after "ExcelApplication.connect", it works :/
ExcelApplication.Visible[lcid] := True;
ExcelApplication.Visible[lcid] := False;
But for me it's not a good way....